# How to give arguments to my R script working with Eclipse and StatET

Tags: r, eclipse, run-configuration, statet

How do i pass (and parse) arguments to my R script using the run configuration option in eclipse?

I am using Eclipse Mars - StatET 3.5.1 - R 3.2.2

Normally from the command line i do something like this:

> Rscript myscript.R argument1 argument2

And in myscript.R:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
file1 <-args[1]
file2 <-args[2]
#do some stuff with file1 and file2
```

For testing python scripts, i use the run configuration option and create a list of arguments there.
This seems to be an option for R as well. But i cannot seem to get this to work.

I go to Run Configurations -> R Console and add the arguments to the Options/Arguments section under "Main" in the right panel for my new run configuration.

But if i press Run, it just opens a new R session and all arguments seem to be forgotten.
My object browser shows 'args' as an empty string

Any thoughts on how to pass the arguments so my R session knows them?

Many Thanks! 
Linda

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found the answer myself. 
If I go to Run Configurations -> R Console and add the arguments to the Options/Arguments section, I needed to provide the specific .R script as argument too and then the arguments Like this:

> myscript.R --args argument1 argument2

After running, it starts the console and executing this:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

gives me access to my arguments.